# Area of a parametrized 2-manifold

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, manifolds

In Munkres' *Analysis on Manifolds*, the following is given as exercise 25.2 (paraphrased):

> Let $\alpha,\beta,f$ be real-valued $C^1$ functions on $[0,1]$ with $f>0$. Suppose $M$ is a 2-manifold in $\mathbb{R}^3$ whose intersection with $z=t$ is the circle
> $$(x-\alpha(t))^2+(y-\beta(t))^2=(f(t))^2~;~z=t$$
> When $t \in [0,1]$, and is empty otherwise. Find the area of $M$ when $\alpha,\beta$ are constant and $f(t)=1+t^2$.

To do this, I first parametrized $M$ by the coordinate patch $h:A=(0,2\pi) \times (0,1) \to \mathbb{R}^3$ given now: $$h(\theta,t)=(\alpha(t)+f(t)\cos(\theta),\\\beta(t)+f(t)\sin(\theta),\\t).$$

I then computed $Dh$ and $V(Dh)$. Assuming $\alpha,\beta$ had zero derivative, I get that $\int_M\,\mathrm{d}V =\int_AV(Dh)=\int_A(1+t^2)\sqrt{1+4t^2}$. However, I can only evaluate this integral in terms of hyperbolic trigonometric functions. This makes me think my solution is incorrect, but I see no mistake in my work. I would appreciate if someone could point out my error, if I did make one.

Comment: You get my award for the cutest (if most obvious) pun in your user name :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just realized that the integral $\int_A(1+t^2)\sqrt{1+4t^2}$ is exactly the one I would arrive at if I used the standard 'surface area of surface of revolution' formula from introductory calculus. So, in fact, my work *is* correct. The exact evaluation of the integral is just not very nice.